# jQuery UI position utility within firefox extension

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, firefox-addon

In my firefox extension, I need to display a heavy weight tooltip near an element which is created dynamically by my extension. I am trying to use jquery ui position utility. The problem is I will have the tooltip box directlty below `<html>` and the element to which I need to show tooltip will be within `<body>`.

When I position the tooltip, it is able to calculate the x position correctly. But fails to calculate the y position.

code example:

```
<html>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(e){
   $("#heavyToolTip").position({
    "my" : "top left",
    "at" : "center left",
    "of" : $("#element") 
   });
   });
</script>
<div id="heavyToolTip">
  <blah blah>
</div>
<body>
  <div id="element">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Hmm... it failed calculating the x position in my test xD Try changing `"at" : "center left"` to `"at" : "top left"`. Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AQFdj/).

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/MMLxT/1/

This works for me here